# Would this electric drive work?

Tags: general-relativity, mass-energy, centripetal-force

The drive leverages General Relativity's equivalence between matter and energy, paired with centripetal force.

There is a conducting (probably super conductor) ring, think of it like a hamster wheel, where the outside rim has openings such that it makes a series of circuits.  This hamster wheel is spun, probably at very high speed.  Wrapped in and around the wheel are two electromagnets paired with metal cores to direct the magnetic field.  These fields run perpendicular to the openings in the circuits at the rim of the wheel at one side, such that it induces current as the wheel turns, and parallel to the openings in the circuits at the opposite side such that it halts the current flowing in the circuits.

So as the wheel rotates, each circuit first gets a current induced, does ~180 degree rotation and then gets the current negated via another magnetic field.

According to GR, this current should add mass to the circuits in the wheel as it makes half a rotation, which as far as I can tell would make an imbalance in the centripetal force and result in a net force.

Will this work?

Here is a rough diagram of the idea:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The device you've described is too vague to specifically refute. If you want the specific reason this doesn't work, you need to actually specify the magnetic fields, the mass distribution, everything about that system, and compute the force.

From a more general standpoint? No, it won't work. Momentum conservation is a fundamental law of all known physical theories. It doesn't break down just because you threw magnets *and* electricity *and* gravity into the mix.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that the wheel itself would be imbalanced.  For it not to work, the net force from the wheel would have to be cancelled by a force applied somewhere else.  And I suspect there is such a force/s which I haven't accounted for, and defining that force would definitely answer my question.

Comment: @HardlyCurious Depending on the configuration, it's certainly not impossible that the wheel would have a net force on it. In that case the magnet has an equal and opposite net force on it. Of course, you don't need general relativity *at all* for a magnet to be attracted to a current loop.